# Anamorphic corrections of a coorrdinate transform

Tags: coordinate-transformation

This is a question referring to optics / coordinate transform I have to implement:

I want to transform a vector A (R^2*2) to another vector B of the same dimension:

```
 A*TRANS=B
 Trans=[A B
        C D]
```

So Trans is the Transformationmatrix function. If I for instance consider only Rotations A = D and B=-C.

For some reason the people I work for want to correct for everything but anamorphic corrections. Can anybody reference me source (or at least tell) what my constraints are for ABCD in this case?

Comment: Hey solution that i found now:
I transform the system into: 

                         (x_1,y_1...x_n,y_n)=(a,b,c,d)^T*([x 0 0 0][y 0 0 0 ]) 

That is the equivalent of multiplying by matrix Trans=([a 0][0 a]) (no anamprophic corrections)